# Count number of pixels from .msk in Python to derive study area size

Tags: python, numpy, extract-by-mask

Apologies I am totally new to GIS in Python.

I am trying to find out the total area of the Barents Sea mask the NSIDC use to calculate their products and therefore I need to know how many pixels the mask is (so I can derive total area since lat and lon resolution = 25km). However the mask is a numpy .msk format which I am not sure how to process.

The .msk file they use can be downloaded from their FTP
"Arctic_region_mask_Meier_AnnGlaciol2007.msk"> ftp://sidads.colorado.edu/DATASETS/NOAA/G02135/seaice_analysis/

and is loaded in

```
import numpy as np
regional_mask = np.fromfile('./Arctic_region_mask_Meier_AnnGlaciol2007.msk',dtype=np.uint8).reshape((448, 304))
```

The Barents Sea has the mask value of 8 in the above .msk file, but I do not know how to just find the total pixel count from this value?

Additionally since the .msk does not contain lat/lon I do not know how to reconstruct their lat and lon from a .dat file?

"psn25lats_v3.dat" and "psn25lons_v3.dat" > ftp://sidads.colorado.edu/pub/DATASETS/seaice/polar-stereo/tools/

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. You might want to ask your second question as a separate question since it is not really related to getting the count number of pixels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the count of pixels with a value of 8 by [boolean masking](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) the array and summing the result (i.e. all the pixels with these values become `True` which corresponds to 1).

```
count = (regional_mask == 8).sum()
```

Comment: Alternatively, `np.count_nonzero(regional_mask == 8)`